# chrome.mediaGalleries / cannot read property 'getMediaFileSystems'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have some problem with chrome app:

I need to get a local img, but chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystems does not work.

But its already added to permission : 
"mediaGalleries":["read","allAutoDetected"]

Where can be a problem?

```
  chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystems(
  {interactive: 'no'},
  function(mediaFileSystems){
    mediaFileSystems.forEach(
      function(item, indx, arr){
        var mData = chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystemMetadata(item);
        console.log(mData);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [chrome.mediaGalleries](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries) docs again. It's `getMediaFileSystems` not getMediaFileSystem. There's an 's'.

Also, check the full chrome app sample in [chrome-app-samples/samples/media-gallery](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/media-gallery/media-gallery.js).